# Content security policy - refused to load image

Tags: javascript, html

I am loading images like so in my site:

```
<img src="https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sdgsdgs-c0b9-4d9d-4124-51caf4d7dbfa/d911efed-7d49-46ce-870e-124125125" alt="" class="Avatar">
```

and have randomly started getting the following error in the console along with the image not being able to load:

> Refused to load the image 'https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sdgsdgs-c0b9-4d9d-4124-51caf4d7dbfa/d911efed-7d49-46ce-870e-124125125' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob: *.anothersite.com *.sentry.io". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

> profile:1 Refused to load the image 'https://my-bucket.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/sdgsdgs-c0b9-4d9d-4124-51caf4d7dbfa/d911efed-7d49-46ce-870e-124125125' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' blob: data:".

I have tried adding in the following Meta tag after doing some research into the issue but I still get the same error:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
  content=" worker-src blob:; child-src blob: gap:; img-src 'self' blob: data:; default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: gap: content:">
```

Any idea why I am still seeing the issue?

Comment: The url you pasted redirects

Comment: It's a dummy URL

Comment: It is sensitive information so I can not paste the actual URL in here